# UIPanGestureRecognizer in Playgrounds

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm playing with playgrounds (awesome, right?)

If I want the pinch gesture using the simulator I can use option and move the mouse to perform the pinch gesture.

The same combination does not do anything in Playgrounds.

For some example code you can copy-pasta the following:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let clickableView = UIView()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        clickableView.backgroundColor = .blue

        view.addSubview(clickableView)

        clickableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        clickableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        clickableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        clickableView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        clickableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        clickableView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
        clickableView.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)
    }

    @objc func handlePinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {        
        guard let gestureView = sender.view else {
          return
        }

        gestureView.transform = gestureView.transform.scaledBy(
          x: sender.scale,
          y: sender.scale
        )
        sender.scale = 1
    }

    @objc func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let targetView = sender.view else {return}
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
        targetView.center = CGPoint(x: targetView.center.x + translation.x
            ,y: targetView.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Is there any way to test a pinch gesture in Playgrounds?

Answer (score 0):

You actually *can* use the option key to do two-finger gestures in playgrounds, but it's kind of finicky.

1. You need to make sure to click on the live view first. Sometimes this doesn't work – if not, keep re-running your playground until your cursor becomes a little pointing hand when you hover over the live view. Then click the view and hold option. You should see at least one gray circle around your mouse pointer.
2. The starting center point of the two gray circles that represent your two fingers is actually in kind of a weird place. In my experimentation, it's always at `CGPoint(x: 384, y: <half of your live view's height>)`, probably because the device that playgrounds use is an iPad Pro (9.7-inch), which has a screen size of 768x1024 (and 384 = 768 / 2). So if you don't see the other circle after doing (1) above, either try making your live view bigger, like 768x1024, or use the shift key while holding option to drag the other circle into view. It's tricky, but can be done; you have to move your mouse to the right side of the live view, hold option + shift, drag to the left side of the live view, release shift (but *not* option), drag to the right side again, and then repeat a few more times until you see two gray circles.

Proof that this can be done in a playground:

[image: Two-finger circles in a playground]